# suggestion for file rename GUI app for OpenSUSE/KDE

Tags: kde, opensuse

I am currently using Windows and one of the app I frequently use is something called Advanced Renamer.

One of the features I often use is the ability to append/prepend folder names to file names.

example:

```
-folder1
 - folder11
   - folder1-folder11-test.txt
 - folder1-test.txt
```

I would also like these additional features:

1. ability to change file to an an incrementing with the option to pad zeroes (example: image001.jpg or image0001.jpg or image01.jpg)
2. ability to remove, insert or replace text in the filename

Any ideas for a GUI app with these features? Thanks

Comment: Softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Krename](http://www.krename.net/home/), "a powerful batch renamer for KDE", has a lot of features. Here's a sampling...

> - renaming of single files
> - renaming of complete directories
> - recursive directory scanning with Wildcards (e.g. *.mp3)
> - renaming of directory names
> - renaming of huge numbers of files (more than 10.000)
> - renaming of filename and extension

---

> - sort files in directories
> - search and replace using regular expressions
> - change file name and/or extension to:
>
>   - lower case (e.g. krename.png)
>   - caps (e.g. KRENAME.PNG)
>   - first character in word to caps (e.g. Krename.png)
> - numbering of files (start,steps,skips definable)
> - create subdirectories while renaming

---

I'm not sure if you can append folder names to names of contained files in one step but given the extensive functionality I'm sure you can automate that work in some way.

"Remove, insert or replace text in the filename" is certainly available.

And as you can see in this screen capture sequential numbering and number padding are present:

[image]

Note: I've only experimented a bit with this app (when I was playing around with KDE in a Cygwin/X setup) but I remember it being pretty solid.

**Update:** A couple other options mentioned over on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27069/graphics-tool-to-rename-files-in-batch-mode). Except for the one I mention here they're not KDE specific but it may be worth reading.